# Hiding the status bar with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, statusbar

How do you hide the status bar for iOS or Android when developing with React Native? I've imported StatusBar, but I believe there is also StatusBarIOS and a StatusBar for Android.

Comment: FYI, `StatusBarIOS` is deprecated. `StatusBar` is now the standard component across platforms.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Figured out how to hide the status bar. First of all, StatusBarIOS is [deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbarios.html) so you need to import `StatusBar` and then simply include this code snippet at the top of your render:

```
<StatusBar hidden />
```

[React Native Docs on `StatusBar`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar)

Comment: You don´t need the ={true} - <StatusBar hidden /> is enough

Comment: It hides StatusBar for all the components. anyway to hide it from specific component?

Comment: @KaranBhutwala In that particular render section add this code

Comment: I am using "react-native": "0.44.2" and Android Emulator Nexus_6_API_25. When I set <StatusBar hidden />, it is working great until the first refresh. After the first refresh I have to update my page some times to hide a status bar in android. How can I fix it?

Comment: @KaranBhutwala did you find a way todo this? (hide for particular components)

Comment: Reload the component if it doens't work after just hot-reloading.

Comment: Not working in iOS too. It works in hot reload after reloading the app it not worked

Comment: `import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';`

Answer (score 81):

You can invoke this method from anywhere in your component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

class MyComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
       StatusBar.setHidden(true);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This will hide the status bar for the entire app and not just in your specific component, to solve this you can do:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
     StatusBar.setHidden(false);
}
```

Or calling this method with false from somewhere else.

Comment: missing apostrophe (')  on import React, { Component } from 'react;

Comment: Yes, its working, but its hiding status bar for every of the screen, even if I did it in the splash only.

Comment: This answer resolves my 3 problems, Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

**For Hidden**:

```js
StatusBar.setHidden(true, 'none');
```

**For Show**:

```js
StatusBar.setHidden(false, 'slide');
```

Answer (score 11):

I prefer the simple way of importing the **StatusBar** component and passing **true** to **hidden** prop...

So Simply:

```js
import React from "react";
import { StatusBar, View, Text } from "react-native";

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
       return (
        <View>
          <StatusBar hidden={true} />
          <Text>Hello React Native!</Text>
        </View>
       )
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an identical answer to the chosen one.

Comment: This one includes the import. @NirBen-Yair

Answer (score 8):

*From version 0.?? to current (0.55 / June 2018)*

```
<StatusBar hidden />
```

Credit to the first comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36186625/3377049)

Remember to first import the [StatusBar component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html) as per the other answers here

Answer (score 0):

If your reason for hiding it is to prevent your components from overlapping it, you might prefer to just use SafeAreaView as follows:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Text>Hello World!</Text>
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

It should be the parent component of a screen and can optionally use a `backgroundColor` to match the color of your screen. Make sure to set a `flex` attribute. Your components will now just take up any area not being used by the status bar. This is especially useful in getting around the 'notch' issue with some of the newer phones.

SafeAreaView is a component of react-native so you will need to make sure you add it to your imports:

```
import { SafeAreaView, Text, View } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: <StatusBar hidden /> is the correct way to do this.... I'm newbie at this field and I think SafeAreaView only work on ios

Answer (score 0):

to make it transparent on android you can do this

```
<StatusBar  backgroundColor={'#ffffff00'} />

{Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />}
```

also `<StatusBar hidden />` is hidden it but you may see a margin on top

Comment: I wrote it in componentDidMound method but still status bar is showing. do I need to update info.plist too?

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't worked doesn't matter what you have tried?

Maybe there is another `<StatusBar hidden="false">` in your code. And it is deeper than your definition. This will replace your previous `hidden="true"` setting.

```
<View>
  <StatusBar hidden={true} /> // this will be replaced by the deeper StatusBar tag
  
  <View>
    <StatusBar hidden={false} /> // remove this or put your `hidden="true"` here
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

...

<StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
```

If your background makes hard to see the bar's icons, you can add `barStyle="dark-content"` to your `StatusBar`