# How to show the status bar and hide status bars in main screens and subscreens

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I need to show status bars in all my main screens and need to hide the status bars in all subscreens.

I have tried with the component StatusBar in react-native, but it shows the status bar for entire screens also it not hiding the status bar.

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor='blue' barStyle='light-content' />
```

Also, I have added the above line in only one main screen. But it changed for all screens.

Any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try with the following code.

```
<StatusBar hidden=true />
```

or

More details find [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar)

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186385/hiding-the-status-bar-with-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

add this to header component

```
<StatusBar hidden={this.props.hidden}/>
```

then you can pass prop {hidden} Boolean