# React native hide StatusBar completely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, statusbar

I want to hide StatusBar completely and not just do that:

```js
<StatusBar hidden/>
```

Because this just hide the text and not the big rectangle (in white on the top):
How to hide completely the `StatusBar`? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/64450679

Comment: @Manojkanth there is no answer in there

Comment: Yes, but on IOS `barStyle="light-content"` does nothing..

Comment: but you cant hide ios statusbar right? as far i know if you hide that your app may get reject. But im not sure.

Comment: I am not sure about that:
- games hide statusbar
- instagram, tiktok hide it when you shot a video

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure a SafeArea or some other layout style is not pushing your body off the top of the screen? `<StatusBar hidden />` should remove the bar completely.

Comment: Yes I am. I have the same height and width. No change...